# Discord Bot Python QuickMath Duels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, nextcord

i am trying to create a discord bot in python and i want a quick math command.

*cogs/duel.py*

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord
import random

class Duel(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    # *duel
    @commands.command()
    async def duel(self, ctx, member: nextcord.Member):
        #operation = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
        await ctx.send(1 + 1)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Duel(bot))
```

this is the code from the part where i put my duel commands.

when i do the command, this error show up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDUFd.png

help
*i am not really good in python please dont juge me :/*

Comment: How did you call the command? The error says that you didn't input a valid member

Comment: the command is 
*duel
do i need to put it like
*duel @exemple#0000

Comment: Yes, since you added `member` argument in the function, you will have to call the command with a member, eg `*duel @example`

Comment: @XYink you can also use a `commands.MemberConverter` which does convert the argument to a Member if it's in the cache. Make sure to mention the member since you're using `discord.Member`

Comment: its working if i do *duel @someone thanks you